# typescript constructor new object

Tags: typescript, constructor, new-operator

What is the meaning of the second parameter in the constructor:

(from this [example](https://github.com/jeffbcross/aim/blob/master/src/services/RxWebSocket.ts))

```
constructor(private url: string, private WebSocketCtor: { new(url:string): WebSocket } = WebSocket) {}
```

Especially the `= WebSocket` part at the end. Why do I need this? In the example above it is called like this:

```
bootstrap(AimApp, [
  ...,
  provide(RxWebSocket, {useFactory: (url:string) => {
    return new RxWebSocket(url, WebSocket);
  }, deps: [SOCKET_URL]})
]);
```

Since I am not very familiar with Angular, how would you call it otherwise?

Comment: `=` means that the perimeter is optional because of default value is provided. The default value is on the right hand side

Comment: But the WebSocket must have a parameter "url". Wouldn't that cause an error if I did not pass a value and the default value was taken?

Comment: I think you're confused because the defaulted parameter is not the URL it's the constructor function

Comment: I understand that the constuctor funtion is optional, but what I do not understand is, how is the class Websocket initialized without a parameter, even though it does not have a default constructor? But I missed that in the example: let socket = this.socket = new this.WebSocketCtor(this.url); Now it makes more sense! Thanks.

Comment: The name of the parameter is `WebSocketCtor`, where "Ctor" means constructor which means class. The name tells you what it is. And indeed the type requires that a url be specified when it is `new`ed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{ new(url:string): WebSocket }` this defines a constructor signature, which is used to hold class constructors. `= WebSocket` provides a default value for the parameters, the `WebSocket` class.

The point of this is to allow the user to plug in a custom `WebSocket` class, which is compatible with the `WebSocket` class, but also provides a default implementation by providing a default value for the `WebSocketCtor` parameter